# FFmpeg - merge videos with different rotation

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I work with FFmpeg on Android. I have 2+ videos - from front-camera and main-camera. And I want to merge them into one video.

But videos from front-camera are upside-down. Rotation of video from fr.camera - 270, from main - 90.

How can I merge them properly?
Now I use this:

```
val inputCommand = arrayListOf<String>()
    inputCommand.add("-noautorotate")
    inputCommand.add("-i")
    inputCommand.add(videoPath)
    inputCommand.add("-map_metadata")
    inputCommand.add("0")

    if (angle.equals("270", true)) {
        inputCommand.add("-metadata:s:v:0")
        inputCommand.add("rotate=180")
    }

    inputCommand.add("-codec")
    inputCommand.add("copy")
    inputCommand.add("-preset")
    inputCommand.add("ultrafast")
    inputCommand.add("-b:v")
    inputCommand.add("1500k")
    inputCommand.add(outputFile.path)
    inputCommand.add("-y")
```

But it doesn't work. **-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=180** doesn't do anything.
I also tried to use **-vf transpose=1,transpose=1** but it doesn't have effect too.

What to do?

ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990

Input and Output metadata doesn't change.

```
Metadata:
  rotate          : 270
```

Comment: Show complete output of `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -i input3`.

Comment: Facing same problem! How to merge fron csm & back cam videos using ffmpeg.Did you find solution?.Thanks in advance.