# Android - merge videos taken with front and back cameras

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-camerax, mp4parser, mobile-ffmpeg

I am having an orientation problem when merging videos taken with front and back cameras in portrait, recorded using Android CameraX.

This issue is explained [here](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/issues/130), but I am yet to find a working solution. I have tried multiple solutions, such as using **mp4parser** as suggested in the issue explanation, but the result is a that every alternate camera video is upside down.
I also tried using **FFmpeg** for android - [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg).
Using ffmpeg Concat demuxer resulted in the same result as mp4parser did.

Concat demuxer command I used: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4`

I also tried changing the rotation metadata of the videos to match before concatenating, similar to how it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186977/ffmpeg-merge-videos-with-different-rotation), but that did not seem to have any effect on the end result.

Lastly, I used ffmpeg Concat filter. That solution took longer obviously because of the re-encoding of the video but it did fix the problem of the orientation of the videos, but the output video quality was poor.

Concat filter command:

```
ffmpeg -i front1.mp4 -i rear1.mp4 -i front2.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] \
concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Has anyone found a solution on how to fix the orientation problem in android? or maybe how can I keep the videos quality as much as possible when using the FFmpeg Concat filter to merge the videos?

Comment: Copy and paste the complete output of `ffmpeg -i front1.mp4 -i rear1.mp4 -i front2.mp4`

Comment: I fixed the quality issue when merging the videos using the Concat filter but this takes pretty long time, is there a way that I can merge the videos taken with front and back cameras without the slow re encoding - like the Concat demuxer does, but without the orientation problem?

Comment: Need to see file info to be able to give you an answer. Copy and paste the complete output of `ffmpeg -i front1.mp4 -i rear1.mp4 -i front2.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

For any one who encounters this issue like I did in android, I have finally solved it by using FFmpeg Concat demuxer(mp4parser can be used as well for this), the key was providing video files with 0 for the rotation metadata. Those videos were recorded using [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) `takeVideoSnapshot()`.

Answer (score 0):

for reduce the processing time, you can use the libx264 coding.
In this [link](https://write.corbpie.com/ffmpeg-preset-comparison-x264-2019-encode-speed-and-file-size/) you can see the different preset available.

example :

```
ffmpeg -i front1.mp4 -i rear1.mp4 -i front2.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] \
concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [vv] [aa]" \
-map "[vv]" -map "[aa]" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```